# How to have all menu boxes within screen

Tags: html, css

My menu boxes and some other stuff at the bottom of the page trespassing the container (see image - the main container is the pale yellow area). How can I get all the page within that container?

[image]

I have tried different things, style is from bootstrap (included with : %include;css). i have change flex display specifications ... noting work. Code is a script made for Geneweb genealogy program. It must be a simple modification I don't get.

```
<!--****************************books******************-->
    
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    
      <div class="h4 text-lg-center"><i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-sm fa-fw text-secondary mr-1""></i>[*tools]1</div>
    
         <div class="d-flex flex-sm-wrap">
    
         <!-- *************************première rangée************************** -->
    
    
         <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
              href="http://genepoulin.net/">
              <i class="fa fa-home fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    
    
            %if;(wizard and not base.has_notes)
              <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
                href="%prefix;m=MOD_NOTES">[*add base notes]</a>
            %end;
    
            %if;base.has_notes;
              <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
                href="%prefix;m=NOTES">
                %if;(bvar.base_notes_title="")
                  <i class="far fa-file-alt fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*base notes]
                %else;%bvar.base_notes_title;%end;
              </a>
            %end;
    
    
            %if;base.has_notes;
              <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
                href="%prefix;m=NOTES&f=Chroniques_familiales">
                %if;(bvar.base_notes_title="")
                  <i class="fa fa-book-reader fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> [*chronicles]
              </a>
            %end;
    
            %if;(bvar.disable_forum != "yes")
              <a class="btn  btn-outline-primary mr-1"
                href="%prefix;m=FORUM"><i class="far fa-comments fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*forum]</a>
            %end;
    
    
    <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary%if;(has_history and bvar.history="yes") mr-1%end;"
              href="%prefix;m=ANM"><i class="fa fa-birthday-cake fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*anniversaries]</a>
    
            %if;has_misc_notes;
              <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
                href="%prefix;m=MISC_NOTES"><i class="fas fa-align-justify fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*base index notes]</a>
            %end;
    
          <!--*************************************deuxième rangée******************-->
    
          <div class="d-inline-flex justify-content-lg-center mt-1 mt-lg-2">
    
            %if;(bvar.propose_place_surnames!="no")
              <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
                href="%prefix;m=PS&bi=on&ba=on&ma=on&de=on&bu=on">
                <i class="fas fa-globe fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*places]/[surname/surnames]0</a>
            %end;
    
            %if;(bvar.hide_advanced_request = "no")
              <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
                href="%prefix;m=H;v=advanced">
                <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*advanced request]0</a>
            %end;
    
            <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
              href="%prefix;m=CAL">
              <i class="far fa-calendar-alt fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*statistics]</a>
    
            <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
              href="http://genepoulin.net/geo/">
              <i class="fa fa-map fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*map]</a>
    
            <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1"
              href="http://genepoulin.net/gallery/">
              <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*photos]</a>
    
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
       <!--***********************************dictionnaires**********************-->
    
      %if;wizard;
    
      <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    
      <div class="h4 text-lg-center"><i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-sm fa-fw text-secondary mr-1""></i>[*books]1</div>
    
      <div class="d-flex flex-sm-wrap">
    
            %(<!--<div class="d-inline-flex justify-content-lg-center">-->%)
    
             <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success mr-1"
                href="%prefix;m=MOD_DATA;data=fn"
                title="[*modify] %apply;book_of([first name/first names]1)
                  ([wizard/wizards/friend/friends/exterior]0)">[*first name/first names]1</a>
              <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success mr-1"
                href="%prefix;m=MOD_DATA;data=sn"
                title="[*modify] %apply;book_of([surname/surnames]1)
                  ([wizard/wizards/friend/friends/exterior]0)">[*surname/surnames]1</a>
              <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success mr-1"
                href="%prefix;m=MOD_DATA;data=place"
                title="[*modify] %apply;book_of([places])
                  ([wizard/wizards/friend/friends/exterior]0)">[*places]</a>
              <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success mr-1"
                href="%prefix;m=MOD_DATA;data=occu"
                title="[*modify] %apply;book_of([occupation/occupations]1)
                  ([wizard/wizards/friend/friends/exterior]0)">[*occupation/occupations]1</a>
              <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success"
                href="%prefix;m=MOD_DATA;data=src"
                title="[*modify] %apply;book_of([source/sources]1)
                  ([wizard/wizards/friend/friends/exterior]0)">[*source/sources]1</a>
    
            %if;(has_history and bvar.history="yes")
              <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success%if;(bvar.disable_forum!="yes") mr-1%end;"
                href="%prefix;m=HIST;k=20"><i class="fas fa-history fa-fw mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>[*history]</a>
            %end;
    
            %if;(wizard and bvar.propose_add_family != "no")
              <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success mr-1"
                href="%prefix;m=ADD_FAM"
                title="[*add::family/families]0 ([wizard/wizards/friend/friends/exterior]0)"><i class="fas fa-user-plus mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            %end;
    
            %if;((bvar.wizard_passwd_file != "" or bvar.wizard_descr_file != "")
                 and (wizard or wiznotes_dir_exists)
                 and bvar.authorized_wizards_notes = "yes")
    
      <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success mr-1"
                href="%prefix;m=WIZNOTES"><i class="fas fa-star mr-1" aria-hidden%"true"></i></a>
            %end;
            </div>
          </div>
        %end;
```

Comment: Please provide rendered HTML, not whatever templating that is, and simplify it to just what's needed to show the problem. We don't need every button. Put it and your CSS in a snippet demo using the editor. See [ask] for tips. Links to other sites aren't allowed. Also tag your version of Bootstrap. That's critical information.

Comment: I have modified the code - its now a bit better but still boxes get out of container when viewed with a phone

Comment: You're still showing us stuff that's not HTML. That should not be there. As I suggested,  put it and your CSS in a snippet demo using the editor. It's not difficult if you take the time to get familiar with the editor toolbar.

Comment: You have 2 options:  with flex, you need to use `flex-wrap: wrap` to break in a new row or with scroll, you can use `overflow: auto`